# Android Studio UI horizontal divider is too thick in Android application

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, mobile-application

I would like to have a less thickness for the dividers separating some login/signup forms. All good layout practices have been followed - ConstraintLayout has been used in the Activity and constraints have been set to match parent.

[Here is how my application looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nNIe.jpg)

Here is the activity layout XML portion of one divider (they are all the same):

```
    <View
    android:id="@+id/signup_divider"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="156dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with ContraintLayout and its match parent height constraint (0dp) it can stretch to a space that is more than what I want visually, which results in a thicker divider.

So, we can use static height (thickness) for the divider that is visually appealing. It looks good now once I set it to:

```
 android:layout_height="1dp"
```